# Fedora 21 Sound stopped working when installing the 4.0.4 kernel

Tags: linux, audio, drivers, fedora, kernel

Today I did a yum update as part of my attempts to get my qemu-kvm vm up and running.
It appears to have had a side effect I didn't anticipate.

Other than qemu itself, the only other thing that updated was the linux kernel (from 3.19.7 to 4.0.4).
Ever since then I have lost all sound.
Pulseaudio still shows the Line being plugged in, and still shows the bar under the mixer level for the media player going up and down with the sounds as it should, but no actual sound is leaving my PC.

Unfortunately I can't re-download the kernel-devel for 3.19.7 (it's not in the repo anymore for some reason) so i can't revert to the older kernel as I would have to re-install my Nvidia driver (I install the newest driver from the .run file supplied by Nvidia)

I honestly don't even know where to begin with this issue, other than checking pulseaudio and alsamixer to make sure nothings turned down or muted (everythings maxed and unmuted in both)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Re acquire and install 3.19.7  from here if needed [koji build system](http://koji.fedoraproject.org/koji/buildinfo?buildID=635515)
Also why are you  using the .run when the drivers are natively in  rpmfusion repos?

(given that you are  using  the .run the kernel devs can't / won't help debug it as the kernel is considered "tainted")

Try mitigating by :

1) install nvidia  from  rpmfusion repos (while still "technically" tainted the devs help debug that.

2) try with

> nomodeset

in your kernel line.

what audio card is this again ?

Comment: Thanks for the link to koji, I didn't know there was a site like that ahaha.
I will first try reverting to the last known working configuration (3.19.7 with .run nvidia drivers.

If that succeeds, i'm sure it can rule out the nvidia driver as being the problem, however I will continue to debug the 4.0.4 kernel with nomodset 

The reason I use the .run instead of rpmfusion repos is because the rpmfusion repo doesn't always have the newest driver
RPMFusion offers 346 and the .run is 352.09I will post back within the next 20mins with my results of downgrading back to 3.19.7.

Comment: Also, it's the on-board soundcard on the Asus Sabertooth 990FX.  Idk what card they use and i don't have the manual anymore, sorry, but it's not a pci sound card.

Comment: Ok, sound is NOT working with any kernel. Tried with 4.0.4, 3.19.7, 3.19.5 and 3.17.5
None of which had sound working.
Tried with nvidia driver from .run, from rpmfusion, and tried nomodset no change so I doubt it's the nvidia driver causing a conflict.

I'm out of ideas other than removing and reinstalling everything sound-related which would be a major clusterfuck.  
yum reinstall alsa* pulse*  had no effect at all.

Comment: mind a fpaste --sysinfo share?

Comment: http://ur1.ca/mp23o

Comment: Looks like you should be using Korora to be totally honest with that repolist  but  try sudo dnf (or dnf-yum) upgrade alsamixer-plugin-pulseaudio and FULL shutdown  (no reason you should have 4  active sessions (same user)  in the graphical ACTIVE concurrently)

Comment: [Galaxy@Amathorian ~]$ sudo dnf upgrade alsamixer-plugin-pulseaudio
Using metadata from Wed May 27 14:50:27 2015 (3 days, 20:45:05 hours old)
No match for argument: alsamixer-plugin-pulseaudio
Error: No packages marked for upgrade.
[Galaxy@Amathorian ~]$ sudo dnf-yum upgrade alsamixer-plugin-pulseaudio
sudo: dnf-yum: command not found

I've honestly never even heard of that distro lol.  I'm going to try a full shutdown and boot up, then I'm going to try booting up my windows and see if I have sound issues on that, some research shows this mobo has sound issues sometimes.

Comment: alsa-plugins-pulseaudio my bad  (typo)

Comment: sudo [Galaxy@Amathorian ~]$ sudo dnf upgrade alsa-plugins-pulseaudio
Dependencies resolved.
Nothing to do.
  I've also tried booting into Windows, and have the same issue. Mixer levels reflect sound being played but nothing actually comes out of the speakers. Plugged speakers into my phone and they work just fine. Tried reinstalling the realtek driver from the asus site and it didn't help. Since this problem exists on both Linux and Windows i've determined it's a problem with the MOBO itself and was just coincidence it died when I upgraded the kernel. Going to invoke the warranty from ASUS.

Comment: I'm going to make your original reply as the solution, because you've been very helpful.

Comment: Before invoking that warranty  check alsamixer one last time  on ANY / ALL  kernels ,    Also ALL abrt logs are gonna go un-attented/assigned by the devs due to the overly "tainted" nature of that build FYI -- would likely get more help that way from the Korora guys NOT fedora

Comment: I've checked it on all 3 kernels that I still have (4.0.4, 3.19.7 and 3.19.5) and each one has the same issue, everythings up to date, mixer shows a line plugged in and the levels show sound is being pushed to the sound card. When I record an audio file with my USB microphone, the mixer shows it's playing audio when I playback the file. Likely some defect with the soundcard jacks on the mobo. Some research into it shows this isn't an unheard of problem with the sabertooth 990fx r2.0 boards.